# Invalid Next control variable reference when splitting sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have to split out data into multiple sheets. I have used a well known code found online and edited myself however I am getting an 'Invalid Next control variable reference' for Next group and I have looked at some similar questions on here but still cant figure it out. Any help is much appreciated.

```
  Sub split_data()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim pdata As Range
    Dim dg As Range
    Dim group As String
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("main")
    
    With ws
    
        Set pdata = .Range("A1:E" & Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
        .Range("E2:E" & Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=.Cells(1, Columns.Count), Unique:=True
    
        For Each dg In .Range(.Cells(1, .Columns.Count), .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).End(xlUp))
    
            group = dg.Text
    
            If WksExists(group) Then
    
                Sheets(group).Cells.Clear
    
            Else
    
    
                Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
    
                wsNew.Move After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    
                wsNew.Name = group
    
            End If
    
            pdata.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=group
    
            pdata.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(group).Cells(1, 1)
    
        Next group '???? No any group iteration variable
    
     End With
    
     ws.Columns(Columns.Count).ClearContents
    
     pdata.AutoFilter
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Your iteration variable in the for-loop is `dg` - so either you write `Next dg` or just `Next`.

Comment: Be careful to the code indentation. In this way you will faster understand what @FunThomas suggested. You do not have a `group` iteration variable. It must be replaced or replaced with `dg`. I put some question marks there (in a comment) when edited your code...

Comment: Guys, thank you so much, working perfectly and now fully understand.